# Problems initialising browser with options using Ruby, Watir, Chrome

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have a few web-scraping scripts that I've been using for a while now that have been working without issue. However because of an update of something somewhere (I think chrome+chromedriver), the the browsers are not loading with the preferences/options I specify.

Current code:

```
preferences = { 
  :download => {
    :prompt_for_download => false,
    :directory_upgrade => true,
    :default_directory => 'C:/DownloadFolder/', 
  }   
}   
args = ['--disable-infobars']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :chrome_options => {:detach => true, :prefs => preferences, :args => args}
```

The problems I'm noticing are that the '--disable-infobars' and download folder location are not being applied.

ruby version: 2.3.3p222

watir version: 6.16.5

selenium webdriver version: 3.142.3

chrome version: 75.0.3770.100

chromedriver version : 75.0.3770.90

Comment: Please write this and check`browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, args: args, options: {prefs: prefs}` It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from help I got elsewhere:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |o|
  o.add_argument('--disable-infobars')   
  o.add_preference(:download, directory_upgrade: true,
                              prompt_for_download: false,
                              default_directory: 'C:\\DownloadFolder\\')   
  o.add_option(:detach, true)  
end                       

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: options
```

Two things solved the problem. 1 is specifying the options through selenium rather that Watir. The other is no longer being able to use single forward slashes in folder paths.